# sql - date not in format specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I have searched a bit, and can't see any questions asked that answer my question, so here it goes.

I am trying to get a date from the database (source is in datetime format, i.e "2015-11-30 00:00:00.000") and select it as date, but in another format. I am using Convert function for this after "googleing". First I set target format as varchar:

```
Select
convert(varchar(10),ac_payout_book_dt,104) as 'Dato'
```

Result is date in correct format, i.e "30.11.2015"

Then I needed to sort it when automating the script, so to be able to use

```
ORDER BY Dato DESC
```

... I changed my query to ...

```
Select    
convert(date,ac_payout_book_dt,104) as 'Dato'
```

Now the result is in the wrong format, i.e "2015-11-30"

After a few rounds on the internet I also tried this without any luck

```
CAST(convert(date,ac_payout_book_dt,104) AS DATE) as 'Dato'
```

Anyone that can help me to figure out where I am going the wrong way?

BR
Andreas

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, added SQL Server to tags now. Running 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you use

```
Select
    convert(varchar(10),ac_payout_book_dt,104) as 'Dato'
```

then you convert your `DateTime` (which internally in SQL Server has no format - it's an 8-byte binary value) to a string - you can control how the date is formatted into the string.

In order to sort your output, you need a date (without the time, I presume) - no problem, but when you do

```
Select    
    convert(date, ac_payout_book_dt, 104) as 'Dato'
```

you're converting your `DateTime` to a `Date` (which in SQL Server *again* has **no format** - it's just a 3-byte bianry value) - so the style "104" is useless here - you're converting one binary value to another binary value - and the date will be displayed in the default SQL Server date formatting.

Since this really is a binary-to-binary conversion, without **string formatting** involved, I prefer to use

```
SELECT CAST(ac_payout_book_dt AS DATE) AS 'Dato'
```

since there's really no point in supplying a style which cannot be used anyway.

So really, what you need to be aware of is this:

- are you using a `DATE` or `DATETIME` for **sorting** or date arithmetic? In that case, you **must use** the native data types - don't do date math on a string representation of a date!
- do you want to **output** your `DATE` or `DATETIME` to the screen? Then you need to convert it to a **string** using `CONVERT` or `FORMAT` and supplying the proper styles / date formatting string

So overall, without knowing your entire query - you probably want to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ac_payout_book_dt, 104) as 'Dato',
    ..... (other columns) .....
FROM
    dbo.YourTable
WHERE 
    .... (some condition) ....
ORDER BY
    CAST(ac_payout_book_dt AS DATE) DESC
```

Or maybe you want to check out [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) which is available from SQL Server **2012** on, that allows for more flexibility in formatting your dates:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(ac_payout_book_at, 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'de-de')
```

Comment: Thank you, marc_s . Really helpful feedback. I seem to have overlooked the basic fact of date and datetime. Sorry for that. Your answer gave me a lot of help.

Comment: @Andreasp: glad I was able to help! We live and learn - every day :-) All of us ....

Comment: @marc_s you explained it superbly. Well job, i got to know something from it.

Answer (score 3):

i guess you should try this, order with `CAST` Date so by this way you will perform your desired operation and you will be able to get your desired date format as well.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ac_payout_book_dt, 104) as 'Dato'
ORDER BY
    CAST(ac_payout_book_dt AS DATE) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert 'Deto' in to 'date' format while sorting. 
Something like this - 
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, Deto, 104) DESC

Comment: You're converting a `DATETIME` to a `DATE` - both are **binary** - this doesn't work, you need to convert to a **STRING** when you want to apply a style (104)